# IndexError: list index out of range when splitting lines

Tags: python, io

I would like to write a function from existing code in python. Code is below working as it:

```
fileName = 'inputFile.txt'
f = open(fileName,'r')
output1 = "PassFile.txt"
output2 = "FailFile.txt"
passFile = open(output1,'w')
failFile = open(output2, 'w')
for line in f:
    line_split = line.split()
    if line_split[2] == "P":
        passFile.write(line)
    else:
        failFile.write(line)
passFile.close()
failFile.close()
```

And function I am writing:

```
def fileIO(inputFile='inputFile.txt'):

    with open(inputFile, 'r') as f:
        f = f.read()
        for line in f:
            line_splint = line.split(" ")
            if line_splint[2] == 'P':
                with open('PassFile.txt', 'w') as PassFile:
                    PassFile.write(line)
            elif line_splint[2] == 'F':
                with open('FailFile.txt', 'w') as FailFile:
                    FailFile.write(line)
            else:
                pass

fileIO()
```

Input file look like this:

```
Mary 25 P
John 32 P
Dylan 19 F
Julia 23 F
Chad 17 F
Jack 20 F
```

So purpose here, I want to generate two files from input file, one includes people with P (passed) another one with F (failed). However, I face with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileIO.py", line 33, in <module>
    fileIO()
  File "fileIO.py", line 24, in fileIO
    if line_splint[2] == 'P':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: can you print the content of line_splint?

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the formatting of your "inputFile.txt". Notice that the error tells you that it's happening when the program tries to access `line_splint[2]`, indicating that `line_splint` has two or less elements. This should not happen if `line` is of the form "Name DD P/F".To debug this, you could `print(line)` within the for loop, to see which is the `line` that causes this error.

Comment: You could check if `len(line_splint) == 2`, since you're expecting that list to have three elements. If it doesn't, it means you are not separating with whitespaces or badly formatting the lines of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the line:

```py
f = f.read()
```

This function reads character by character, but you want read your file line by line. So use `readlines()` function instead of `read()` function:

```py
f = f.readlines()
```

Comment: f = f.readlines() gives me ['Mary 25 P\n', 'John 32 P\n', 'Dylan 19 F\n'] like a list of strings

Comment: Yes it's that and with the loop `for line in f` you can iterate through the lines like you wanted